# Netty - Specifying the number of thread to create

Tags: netty

Let me ask several questions regarding thread with Netty.

Q1. Which thread is created?
According to documentation, following constructor creates multiple threads (2 * the number of avail processors). It means that it creates multiple boss threads or worker threads? My assumption is 1 boss thread and multiple worker thread. Am I correct?

public NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executor bossExecutor, Executor workerExecutor)
Creates a new instance. Calling this constructor is same with calling NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executor, Executor, int) with 2 * the number of available processors in the machine.

Q2. According to the documentation, it seems to me that I can specify the max number of worker thread with following constructor. Can I implicitly specify exact number of worker thread to create - say 16?

public NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executor bossExecutor,
                                     Executor workerExecutor,
                                     int workerCount)
Creates a new instance.
Parameters:
bossExecutor - the Executor which will execute the boss threads
workerExecutor - the Executor which will execute the I/O worker threads
workerCount - the maximum number of I/O worker threads

Q3. Is there any way to know the number of boss and worker threads that currently run?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Which thread is created? According to documentation, following constructor creates multiple threads (2 * the number of avail processors). It means that it creates multiple boss threads or worker threads? My assumption is 1 boss thread and multiple worker thread. Am I correct?

Yes.

> Q2. According to the documentation, it seems to me that I can specify the max number of worker thread with following constructor. Can I implicitly specify exact number of worker thread to create - say 16?

Just specify `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and specify the max number of threads to use as a constructor parameter.

> Q3. Is there any way to know the number of boss and worker threads that currently run?

You can get it via `ThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` assuming you passed `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.  It returns `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so you can keep it somewhere and then query it to see how many threads are actually active.